# Can't refresh crystal report in VB for reports without parameters

Tags: crystal-reports, vb6

I have a legacy VB6 application where I am able to open all reports and even refresh them (with their existing parameter entries).  However, when I refresh reports that don't have any parameters I get error -2147483638/Automation error.  This happens when I try to re-set the report source.  It seems like the rptviewer.IsBusy flag is still set to True and stays that way indefinitely for these specific reports.  If that's the issue, why does the report viewer control stay busy perpetually and how can I "stop" it?  It doesn't seem like the report control is busy in the program as I am able to access the report in other ways.

```
While rptViewer.IsBusy
  DoEvents
Wend

rptViewer.ReportSource = m_CrxReport   '' Error occurs here
rptViewer.ViewReport
```

Again, I don't have any issues opening these reports and I don't have any issues opening and/or refreshing reports that request parameters.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

P.S. The viewer control is version 10 (I know, it's old)